# Laravel: Quotation is not visible in query in seeder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I was trying to deploy a Laravel application in a live server.
The final step is apply migration and seeder to fill admin and a user demo to test application.

But when I type: `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed`, the migration run successfully, but the problem is when apply the first seeder:

```sh
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 SELECT command denied to user 'axcess'@'localhost' for table 'users' (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `lastname`, `email`, `organization`, `password`, `role`, `current_membership_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Axcess, Administrator, diegohdez12+axcessadmin@gmail.com, Axcess, $2y$10$WugXbyh6VXf1qAdwTisbX.h9uYvmXaOO9Gp2OsN9qizj/g5brc20u, administrator, 1, 2021-09-08 18:47:09, 2021-09-08 18:47:09))

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:671
    667|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    668|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    669|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    670|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 671|             throw new QueryException(
    672|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    673|             );
    674|         }
    675|

      +10 vendor frames
  11  database/seeds/UsersTableSeeder.php:43
      Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::insert()

      +7 vendor frames
  19  database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php:14
      Illuminate\Database\Seeder::call()
root@starnet-seven:/var/www/axcess/axcess-backend# mysql -u axcess -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1066
Server version: 5.7.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> use axcess_manage;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> insert into `users` (`name`, `lastname`, `email`, `organization`, `password`, `role`, `current_membership_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Axcess, Administrator, diegohdez12+axcessadmin@gmail.com, Axcess, $2y$10$WugXbyh6VXf1qAdwTisbX.h9uYvmXaOO9Gp2OsN9qizj/g5brc20u, administrator, 1, 2021-09-08 18:47:09, 2021-09-08 18:47:09);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com, Axcess, $2y$10$WugXbyh6VXf1qAdwTisbX.h9uYvmXaOO9Gp2OsN9qizj/g5brc20u' at line 1
mysql> exit
```

And you can see and type the same query in the MariaDB CLI to launch it and I see that the problem is `@` symbol from the email value.

Someone would like to help me i how to fix. When I was developed in localhost the application works with Mysql 5. But in this case is launched into a Ubuntu server with Apache 2 and MariaDB:

```
root@starnet-seven:/var/www/axcess/axcess-backend# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.33, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

There is a way where I can configure laravel in this case to use quotation `"` or in the MariaDB configuration.

To finish my post I shared with you the seeder where laravel launch this error:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

use Carbon\Carbon;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('memberships')->insert([
            'name' => 'Sample',
            'time' => 14,
            'price' => 0.00,
            'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'created_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        ]);
        DB::table('memberships')->insert([
            'name' => 'Sample',
            'time' => 30,
            'price' => 10.00,
            'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'created_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        ]);
        DB::table('users')->insert([
            'name' => 'Axcess',
            'lastname' => 'Administrator',
            'email' => 'diegohdez12+axcessadmin@gmail.com',
            'organization' => 'Axcess',
            'password' => Hash::make('password', [
                'memory' => 1024,
                'time' => 2,
                'threads' => 2
            ]),
            'role' => 'administrator',
            'current_membership_id' => 1,
            'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'created_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        ]);
        DB::table('users')->insert([
            'name' => 'Demo',
            'lastname' => 'Axcess Client',
            'email' => 'diegohdez12+axcessclient@gmail.com',
            'website' => 'http://example.com',
            'organization' => 'Demo',
            'password' => Hash::make('123456789', [
                'memory' => 1024,
                'time' => 2,
                'threads' => 2
            ]),
            'role' => 'axcess',
            'current_membership_id' => 1,
        ]);
    }
}
```

UPDATED: Laravel application is connected with Mysql 5.7.33 as above says. I was confused in the result of the command.

Comment: Does `select * from users` on your DB also show an error? `SELECT command denied to user 'axcess'@'localhost'` makes me think permissions are not right for that user. The missing quotes in the exception message might be a red herring?

Comment: Thanks @Subtlebot. In the `select` query there is no error. `SELECT command denied to user 'axcess'@'localhost'` I don't know why is launching the error if the migrations were execute successfully, the problem comes when laravel launch the first seeder (last snippet of above).

Comment: Also, if you notice. in my seeder launch the first two `insert()` to `Memberships` table and this seeder break when try to insert to `users` table. The error is mysql cannot insert because of `@` and the quotation marks are missing in `values()`

Comment: I notice that in the application is launching a trigger procedure to connect to another database and insert in the data in the second database.